# how to find out if the first char in a string is a letter from the latin alphabet

Tags: objective-c

I have an array with strings. What is the best way to check if the first char of every string in the array is from the latin alphabet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you can use a character set like so:

```
NSString* string = @"This is a string";
NSCharacterSet *letters = [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet];
if([letters characterIsMember:[string characterAtIndex:0]]) {
    // This is a letter
}
```

The example speaks for itself :-)

Comment: it will crash if `string` is empty.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on if you're dealing with Objective-C objects or C (I assume Objective-C, but lets do both)

Objective-C - The array is an `NSArray` of `NSStrings`:

1. Fetch the first item: `NSString *firstString = [array objectAtIndex:0];`
2. Get the range of a letters: `NSRange lettersRange = [firstString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet];
3. Check the range starts at the start of the string: `BOOL isFirstCharALetter = lettersRange.location = 0;`

C -  The array is an array of `char *` (i.e. `char *[]`):

1. Fetch the first item: `char *firstString = strings[0];`
2. Get the first char of the string: `char firstChar = firstString[0];`
3. Check the first char is with the letter range of ASCII chars: `BOOL isFirstCharALetter = (firstChar >= 'A' && firstChar <='Z') || (firstChar >= 'a' && firstChar <='z');`

Comment: What character set does this assume?! last time I checked, in ASCII `'Z' < 'a'` so that last condition will always be false. Furthermore, there's a range of characters between `A-Z` and `a-z`.

Comment: @mvds opps. I rushed that bit. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Simple oneliner:

```
if ( [string length] && iswalpha([string characterAtIndex:0]) )
{
    // stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Defines only alphabet that we will compare with
NSCharacterSet *alphaBetFromAToZ = [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet];
NSCharacterSet *numberFrom0To9 = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];

//My string
NSString *myStringToCheck = @"String";

//Check if string is not empty and if so, make it a not empty string otherwise the app could throw up an exception
myStringToCheck = ([myStringToCheck length] == 0) ? @" ":myStringToCheck;

//Check if first string is from the alphabet
if ([alphaBetFromAToZ characterIsMember:[myStringToCheck characterAtIndex:0]])
{
    //First character is from the alphabet
}
else if ([numberFrom0To9 characterIsMember:[myStringToCheck characterAtIndex:0]])
{
    //First character is a number
}
else
{
    //First character is NOT from the alphabet and also is not a number, is something like @ [ ] $ % ^ ......
}
```